# Morris Area and Line Chart resize function causing memory leak in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

Hi Am using Morris chart in my application.Am having single Div and loading all other page content to this div by jquery load. Id of that div is "thisDIiv"

Morris area chart is one of the child div of thisDiv and thisDiv is in the index page. I have left side menus for changing the page. When i load the index page the morris area chart and all other contents are getting loaded perfectly and click on the left side menu the corresponding page is getting loading but at the same time firefox browser is getting crashed.

If i set resize:false in the Morris area chart there is no memory leak. If i set true only memory leak occurs.And also instead of area and line chart i tried to use bar chart with resize:true its working fine without memory leak.

Morris Area and Line charts only causing memory leak issue. Could you please anyone give me the solution?

Comment: I have the same issue on 0.5.0 version.. Still no solution?

Comment: Read the post for all Morris Chart's resize  [Morris Chart's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38656829/4265604)